# Problem Reloading Child Routes with Resolve in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I have problems reloading the childComponent functions. I have a component that makes a query to a database depending on a parameter received.
When I access this route for the first time, it executes the OnInit function well, but if I change the parameter `:page` it does not do anything.

Here is the component:

```
//temas.children.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-temas-children',
  templateUrl: './temas-children.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temas-children.component.css']
})
export class TemasChildrenComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.route.snapshot.data.temas);

  }
}
```

Routes:

```
//app.routes.ts
//imports and some other routes
{ path: 'temas/:categoria', component: TemasComponent, children:[
{path: ':page', component: TemasChildrenComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: "always", resolve:{temas: TemasResolverService}}
]},
```

Resolver Service:

```
//temas.resolver.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from './crud.service';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TemasResolverService implements Resolve<any>{

constructor(private crudService: CrudService) { }
  resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
    return this.crudService.getTemas(route.parent.pathFromRoot[1].params.categoria, route.paramMap.get('page'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing this.route?

Comment: I'm sorry, copy the code wrong, fixed it